# Automatic Trend Detection for Time Series / Signal Processing

Tags: python, time-series, signal-processing, trend, trendline

What are the good algorithms to automatically detect trend or draw trend line (up trend, down trend, no trend) for time series data?  Appreciate if you can point me to any good research paper or good library in python, R or Matlab.

Ideally, the output from this algorithm will have 4 columns:

1. from_time
2. to_time
3. trend (up/down/no trend/unknown)
4. probability_of_trend  or degree_of_trend

Thank you so much for your time.

[image: Example of Trend Lines]

Comment: If you want just a line look at time series regression. `package forecast` in R

Comment: Thanks ... looking for multiple lines (up, down, and flat) ...

Comment: Okay, you might have to do some transformations to the dates, but MARS can help. Check here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_adaptive_regression_splines

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem - wanted to do segmentation of the time series on segments with a similar trends. For that task, you can use [trend-classifier](https://pypi.org/project/trend-classifier/) Python library. It is pip installable (`pip3 install trend-classifier`).

Here is an example that gets the time series data from YahooFinance and performs analysis.

```py
import yfinance as yf
from trend_classifier import Segmenter

# download data from yahoo finance
df = yf.download("AAPL", start="2018-09-15", end="2022-09-05", interval="1d", progress=False)

x_in = list(range(0, len(df.index.tolist()), 1))
y_in = df["Adj Close"].tolist()

seg = Segmenter(x_in, y_in, n=20)
seg.calculate_segments()
```

Now, you can plot the time series with trend lines and segment boundaries with:

```py
seg.plot_segments()
```

[image]

You can inspect details about each segment (e.g. positive value for slope indicates up-trend and a negative down-trend). To see info about the segment with index `3`:

```py
from devtools import debug
debug(seg.segments[3])
```

You can have information about all segments in tabular form using `Segmenter.segments.to_dataframe()` method which produces Pandas DataFrame.

```py
seg.segments.to_dataframe()
```

There is a parameter that controls the "generalization" factor, i.e. you can try to fit a trend line to a smaller range of time series - you will end up with a large number of segments, or you can go for the segments spanning a bigger part of the time series (more general trend line) and end up with a time series divided into fewer segments. To control that behavior, when initializing `Segmenter()` (e.g. `Segmenter(x_in, y_in, n=20)` use various values for `n` parameter. The larger `n` the generalization is stronger (fewer segments).

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the trend-classifier package.